Serverless offline not logging to console with golang
When using serverless offline, logs aren't logged to console instead returned as an HTTP response when triggered as an endpoint
serverless.yml
service: go-sls # Define your service name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  region: eu-central-1 # Put your AWS region



functions:
  health:
    handler: main.go # route to binary
    events:
      - http:
          path: /health
          method: get
          cors: true
          private: false

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

main.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type Response events.APIGatewayProxyResponse

func Handler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    log.Println("trying log")
    fmt.Println("it prints")
 return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: "It works!", StatusCode: 200}, nil
}

func main() {
 lambda.Start(Handler)
}

Result
fmt.Println isn't logged to the console
log.Println is returned as an http response

Expected Behavior
Both it prints and trying log should be logged to the console
